# Mosquitto log directory gets deleted

Tags: raspbian-stretch, logfiles, mqtt

I have `mosquitto` MQTT broker installed on my raspberry (raspbian-stretch).
Logs are stored in `/var/log/mosquitto`. The raspberry pi was now running for some days an the `/var/log/mosquitto` directory was deleted. Due to that fact the `mosquitto` service was not working correctly anymore. After creating `/var/log/mosquitto` again, also `mosquitto` service worked again.

I don't know what is deleting `/var/log/mosquitto` folder and when this folder is deleted.

Can you please help me to figure out, why `/var/log/mosquitto` is deleted?

Comment: something must be deleting it - I'v been running mosquitto for 2 years, and never lost the log file

Comment: But how can I find what is deleting it?

Comment: How can we? It's not normal

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. I have to blame myself.
Some time ago I experimented with `tmpfs` and used `tmpfs` to move `/var/log` into RAM. Therefore the folder `/var/log/mosquitto` got lost after every reboot. This caused that mosquitto broker could not be started.

It is weird, that mosquitto service states that the service is running although it isn't. This has to be some bug, which I am going to report.